# How do I get a list of scheduled quartz job in spring?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I am having some trouble figuring out how to get the list of scheduled jobs. I have the jobs, triggers, and scheduler declared as beans in my servlet-context.xml file. The job fires correctly and completes. I know I am suppose to use the scheduleFactory to grab a scheduler and do something like:

```
for(String group: sched.getJobGroupNames()) {
    // enumerate each job in group
    for(JobKey jobKey : sched.getJobKeys(groupEquals(group))) {
        System.out.println("Found job identified by: " + jobKey);
    }
```

Though, I do not know how to get the scheduleFactory instance from the bean since I am not suppose to be creating a new one. I have gathered all this info from searching many forums including here.

Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the `scheduleFactory` in your class (using @Autowired if you use annotations).